# Method to store fields in lucene

Tags: lucene

For demo purpose i have 5 documents. After calling the IndexWriter commit function the *.fdx *.fdt files are gone from Indexed Folder. Why they are gone after commit and how they work.

Comment: Good question... even I am looking for the same...

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in the [Javadoc document](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene40/package-summary.html).

Comment: I already read that document. It didn't explain why fdx .fdt files disappear after calling IndexWriter commit method.